# What is the explanation behind this weird layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

In this html text, What forces the `.temp` div to appear above the `.child` div?

```html
  <style>
    .parent {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .child {
      width: 50%;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: green;
    }

    .temp {
      height: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="temp">
    hi
 </div>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The parent div´s height is 100px.The fact that child div has greater height than the parent is ignored by the `.temp` and it calculates only with the parent height of 100px.

By inspecting the browser console you can see that the `<html>` tag has height of 140px.